# How to run selenium python script on already opened chrome browser tab?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to run the selenium python script on the already opened window. As I am using get() method so it always opening a new window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)


driver.get("https://www.nike.ca/")
```

I searched a lot regarding this issue and found a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F-laDV9Pl8
But this video is on Java selenium.

Comment: You can't I guess. I also spent time in order to find a way, but I could not.

Comment: We can do that in Java but not in Python. Isn't its strange?

Comment: I have found the answer. Mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this.
step 1: we have to set an environment variable of chrome application. To do this go to the directory where the chrome application is located. Copy the path and past it to the environment variable.
step 2: make a directory where you will store the remote debugging chrome window. like "D:\Selenium\Chrome_Test_Profile".
step 3: open CMD and write the command chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir="D:\Selenium\Chrome_Test_Profile"
step 4: use following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9014")
#Change chrome driver path accordingly
chrome_driver = path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
print (driver.current_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work far more simply. After determining where Chrome was installed, I opened up a command prompt and entered:

> C:>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir="C:\test\Chrome_Test_Profile"

So there is no need to even add the Chrome installation directory to the system environment PATH variable if you are willing to specify the full path to where Chrome is installed when you start the browser up. You can even create a shortcut on the desktop for this startup specification if you want.

Then my Python script is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:9014')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

try:
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')
    button.click()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Note that my Chrome driver was installed in a directory that is in the system path so I did not have to specify its location as an option.

Comment: Yeah! exactly the same thing I have done but little bit simpler. Thanks for adding your idea.